# How do I unbold text beside javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dreamweaver

I've created a website: [www.mvscaccounting.com](http://www.mvscaccounting.com) and at the bottom of the website I have a search engine made from javascript. Beside it, I wanted to write all rights reserved. However whenever I write anything beside the search engine in dreamweaver, it turns bold!

Problem: I can't get it to unbold! [it's not bold in dreamweaver, but on website it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sz0z6.png)

I tested it out, and the unintentional bold text starts when the javascript form is made. If you go to my website, and view page source you can see all the surrounding code.

**** UPDATE: THE PROBLEM HAS BEEN SOLVED, IT WAS A MISPLACED H3 TAG ****

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's bold because it is inside an `<h3>` element, which is rendered with bold text as defined by the default stylesheet for HTML.

Here's a snapshot of the document in Chrome:

[image]

There are several ways to override this. Try adding this to your stylesheet:

```
.red { font-weight: normal; }
```

This will cause all elements that are marked with `class="red"` to use the normal font-weight, even though they're embedded in an element that should be rendered in bold (like `<h3>`).

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding this rule to the "red" class.

```
font-weight: initial;
```

Comment: I don't think it's the red class, because I've made the class to "none" and it's still bold! I'll try that too though thanks